# Best way to upgrade ember babel

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I installed an addon in my embr application. After that I receive the warning:

```
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at 
least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: frontend -> ember-crumbly -> 
ember-cli-babel
```

What's the best to go about upgrading this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the addon in question and submit a pull request.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. So the addon is out of date. Wasn't sure what exactly was happening. I'll look into that then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded your ember version 'ember-cli-babel' may not have been upgraded at the same time, just install the latest stable release

```
ember install ember-cli-babel
```